# I'm trying to index files in a document through SOLR and lucene..

Tags: java, solr, lucene

as i said in the title: 
i am using Java, but when I run the code on Eclipse, i get the following error..

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/ResourceLoader
>       at Indexer.getIndexWriter(Indexer.java:38)
>       at Indexer.rebuildIndexes(Indexer.java:73)
>       at SolrIndexer.main(SolrIndexer.java:23)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoader
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       ... 3 more

The SAD PART: the class **org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoader** is not available in `Lucene 4.0/3.6/4.0-ALPHA`. although, there are a few webpages where people are talking about the **resourceloader** class.

can anyone help me out here? Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [common analysers](http://upstream-tracker.org/java/compat_reports/lucene/3.6.1_to_4.0.0-BETA/bin_compat_report.html) have been move `lucene-analyzers-common-X.X.X.jar` as a result of [LUCENE-2510](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2510)
Ensure that you have it in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this class: `org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoader` cannot be found. Are you sure that all your required 3rd party libraries are on your class path?

According to [this](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/ResourceLoader.html) API URL, it seems that the interface is available 4.0.0-Alpha. Maybe you could try to revert to this version and see if it works?

Comment: That's what I believed, and hence, I tried 4.0.0-ALPHA. but sadly, it was nowhere to be found ...