# Lucene-SKOS: How to use lucene-skos with Apache SolR-5x?

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud, solr5, skos

So I have successfully implemented Lucene-SKOS with Solr-4x. However whenever I try the same using solr-5x, it throws various errors.

Has anyone tried anything similar? And any pointers on implementing the same in solr cloud  mode?

Comment: try by mentioning only "ukat_examples.n3" instead of /home/tanny/binaries/lucene-skos/docs/solr/ukat_examples.n3

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245202/im-trying-to-index-files-in-a-document-through-solr-and-lucene